# Using "for" loop structure, generating numbers and filtering them by "length" and "% (mod)" structure

Tags: python, numpy, for-loop

(Coding source)

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([2,4,9,10])

psuedo = [arr + 11 * x for x in range(1, 10)] # generate numbers using "arr" values

for i in range(len(arr)): # call each values in "arr"

    if psuedo % arr[i] == 0: # each values in "arr" applies and divides to generated numbers 
        break # if generated numbers are divided by each "arr" values then break
    else:
        print(psuedo) # else, then print.
```

Results:

```
[array([13, 15, 20, 21]), array([24, 26, 31, 32]), array([35, 37, 42, 43]), array([46, 48, 53, 54])]
```

Expected results:

```
[array([13, 15, 21])], array([31]), array([35, 37, 43]), array([53])
```

I expected that the generated each number (results) would be divided by each of 2, 4, 9, and 10, and printed out as long it satisfied `pseudo % arr[i] !=0.`

What is the problem above coding?

Comment: Could you edit your title to be a more accurate representation of the problem? It may help to clarify the core problem here. Try to avoid vague phrases like "help" and "did not work".

Comment: I did. Thanks halfer for your comment!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Honestly I have almost no idea what you try to calculate. But there are some things that might fundamentally not work the way you intend.

- First of all `pseudo % arr[i] == 0` is wrong on multiple levels, I have no idea which Python version you are using that this does not create errors.
- `break` stops the `for`-loop. My guess is that you want to use `continue` (go to next iteration) or `pass` (do nothing) instead (and thus you could simplyfiy the code omitting it completely)

This is my guess:

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.array([2, 4, 9, 10])
pseudo = [arr + 11 * x for x in range(1, 10)]
print([[i for i in x if (i%arr).all()] for x in pseudo])
```

This creates

```
[[13, 15, 21], [31], [35, 37, 43], [53], [57, 59, 65], [75], [79, 87], [97], [101, 103, 109]]
```

Let me explain:

- Looping over arrays `x` inside `pseudo` and the values `i` in `x`, so the first `x` would be `np.array([13, 15, 20, 21])` and the first `i` inthere would be `13`.
- `(i%arr)` is an array `np.array([i%2, i%4, i%9, i%10])`
- `.all()` returns `True` if all values are non-zero, i.e. if your `i` is not divisible by any of the elements in `arr`.
- `[i for i in x if (i%arr).all()]` is a list comprehension, so we create a new list with all elements in `x` that are not divisible by any of the elements in `arr`.
- My output contains lists, but you can simply create `np.array`s if that's better

Comment: I tested your coding, it showed what I expected results! Thanks for your comments and time. Above coding would be used for selecting prime numbers, however, I quite new to both number theory and coding. I will copy your comment and paste in document for further studying. I appreciate your time and help, Snow bunting!

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is that the operation `pseudo % arr[i]` returns a new array of arrays with each array being replaced with the results of modding each element of that array with arr[i]. So then comparing this array of arrays to 0 doesn't make sense. What you probably want to do is iterate through all of the arrays of pseudo, and then filter out the elements from those individual arrays which don't satisfy your condition, like this:

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([2,4,9,10])

pseudo = [arr + 11 * x for x in range(1, 10)]

def is_not_mod(x):
    keep = True
    for mod in arr:
        if x % mod == 0:
            keep = False
            break
    return keep

for idx, array in enumerate(pseudo):
    pseudo[idx] = np.array(list(filter(is_not_mod, array)))

print(pseudo)
```

Comment: @JunhoEom this is because you spelled the variable as `psuedo` and I spelled it as `pseudo`. Change one of the two, and it will work

Comment: Pycharm shows errors below;                                                                              
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Jun/PycharmProjects/Jun/primecal.py", line 9, in <module>
    for idx, array in enumerate(pseudo):
NameError: name 'pseudo' is not defined.                                     Where is the right place to define the pseudo equation? Thanks for your time and comment, awarrier99!

Comment: OK, I will try. Thanks!

Comment: @JunhoEom no problem. My code was meant to build on your code, replacing the for loop with this. I'll edit my answer to provide the entire thing